# Order of Pole (if it is indeed one) in a Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, residue-calculus, integral-transforms

I'm trying to invert the following Laplace Transform using the Cauchy Residue Theorem

$$
F(s)=\frac{p(s)}{sq(s)}
$$

which is subject to the following conditions:

$$p(0)=q(0)=0$$

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{p(s)}{q(s)}\hspace{0.5 cm}\text{is finite}$$

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{p(s)}{s}\hspace{0.5 cm}\text{is finite}$$

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{p(s)}{sq(s)}=\infty$$

The function $q(s)$ has several other zeroes along the negative real axis, which I can easily handle.

The questions I have are:

1. Is $s=0$ is a pole, and if so, am I correct in concluding that it's a pole or Order 1?
2. If it is indeed a first order pole, how do I evaluate the residue?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your function $p,q$ are holomorphic, then yes, $s=0$ is a pole of $F(s) = \frac{p(s)}{sq(s)}$, since $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow 0} F(s) = \infty$. It would be an essential singulartiy, if there additionally existed a sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow 0}s_n=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} F(s_n)\neq \infty$.

Further, it has order $1$, since the function $s\cdot F(s) = \frac{p(s)}{q(s)}$ is holomorphic around $s=0$.

One can calculate the residue of a $m$-th order pole $s_0\in\mathbb{C}$ by $$\operatorname{Res}(F,s=s_0) = \frac{1}{(m-1)!}\left.\frac{d^{m-1}}{ds^{m-1}}\right|_{s=s_0} F(s)\cdot(s-s_0)^m,$$

so in your case it is just $\operatorname{Res}(F,s=0) = \left.\left(\frac{p(s)}{sq(s)}\cdot s\right)\right|_{s=0} = \left.\frac{p(s)}{q(s)}\right|_{s=0}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had suspected that the residue was the limit of $p/q$ at $s=0$, but the rationale you offered clarified a lot for me. And yes, $p(s)$ and $q(s)$ are holomorphic.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can also mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with the explanation ^^

Comment: Ah! So that's what the check mark below is for! I thought merely clicking on the up arrow did the job! Thanks again.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar No, you would not. Maybe it becomes clearer with a general explanation: If $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic around a point $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, it can be written as $$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$$ for coefficients $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ given by $a_n = \frac{f^{n}(z_0)}{n!}$. If $f$ has a pole of $m$-th order in $z_0$, this "becomes" the Laurent series $$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-m}^{-1} a_n (z-z_0)^n+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n \text{ }(*),$$
for $a_{-m},...,a_{-1}\in\mathbb{C}$. Now the Residue is $Res(f,z_0)= a_{-1}$.

Comment: Writing $(*)$ differently, this means that $$f(z) = a_{-m}\frac{1}{z-z_0}^m + ... + a_{-1}\frac{1}{z-z_0} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n, \text{ }(**)$$
so in order to get $a_{-1}$, we multiply both sides by $(z-z_0)^m$, i.e.
$$(z-z_0)^mf(z) = a_{-m}+a_{-m+1}(z-z_0)+...+a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{m-1} + (z-z_0)^m \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n.$$
So if we differentiate this $(m-1)$ times, all negative index coefficients except for $a_{-1}$ vanish and one gets $$\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} \left((z-z_0)^mf(z) \right)= (m-1)!\cdot a_{-1} +  (z-z_0)^m\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

Comment: If one now plugs in  $z=z_0$ and divides by $(m-1)!$, one arrives exactly at the formula for the residue I wrote in my answer. However, note that all of this only works because we multiplied by $(z-z_0)^m$ (or in the case of your question $(s-0)^1 = s$) $-$ this allowed us to lose all the terms we weren't interested in, so that only the residue remained. Multiplying by some other function $q$ with $q(z_0) = z_0$ won't do this job.

Comment: I realised this about 3 mins too late, and hence deleted my comment, but nonetheless, thanks for the explanation again. The Laurent series approach you wrote above is what I was using for a double pole.